# Retrieving/resetting forgotten password on Model Tool in ArcMap toolbox(.tbx)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arctoolbox, authentication

I am using ArcGIS 10.8.

How do I get back the forgotten password on the ModelBuilder or reset the password on an ArcMap toolbox(.tbx)?

Answer (score 1):

We cannot unlock a password-protected ModelBuilder without the original password.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/encrypting-python-toolboxes.htm